# Facebook: Add call to action button for downloading app without deeplinking

Tags: links, facebook

I would like to add a call-to-action button on my Facebook page, that will be linked to an app in the user's relevant app store (iOS Appstore or Android Play Store).

However, Facebook only allows a call-to-action button that deep-links to the app itself. Unfortunately, I don't have any links associated with my app yet, so I can't create the button.

[image]

**Is there a way to create a Facebook call to action button that would only send users to a store, without deep linking to the app?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as Facebook only allows deep linking this isn't possible as far as I am aware. The only way to do something like this is to add a link in your page description which shows in the sidebar.